# [Selenium]Arbitrary error with Firefox Binary

Tags: firefox, selenium, debian, xvfb

I'm running some automated Selenium tests on my Debian server, every hour.

But, randomly, I have this error :

> Failed to connect to binary
>   FirefoxBinary(/usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin) on port 7071;

I run Selenium with a jar file, and I'm using Xvfb as my server is headless.

```
DISPLAY=:7 java -jar /selenium/SeleniumTest.jar
```

I wasn't able to tell why it happens (about 2 times each 5 runs).

Does someone have an idea of what is going on ?

EDIT :

- Selenium : Selenium Java 2.21.0
- Firefox : Mozilla Iceweasel 3.5.16
- Debian : 6.0.4

Comment: What version of firefox and selenium are you using

Comment: I've edited my post. Sorry for the lack of info.

Comment: Will you be able to upgrade your FF version to at least 3.6? Read this - http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/support-for-ancient-browsers/